# File upload timeout Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-5.6

I am using the

> Storage::

to upload files into laravel. It works, i can successfully upload, store, delete, and edit files on the server. But the issue i am having is the weight of the file. Images upload easily, but if i try to upload a .zip with like 20MB it drops. I can see the numbers in the bottom of the browser going all the way to 23 then back to 0, up to like 10% then this pages comes up:

[image]

What is going on? I updated my PHP.INI to allow really large uploads... is Laravel got some restrictions? Does Nginx have its own set of permissions? What am i missing?

Comment: `nginx` has `client_max_body_size` variable. Check yours.

Comment: Okay. Thank you.

Comment: I will go check that out and see if that helps.

Comment: I went and added that to my server file and now the file makes it to 100% finally, after never going above 50. But this is happening after the 100% and file isn't uploaded... its like a timeout ig. : https://prnt.sc/k330tr

Comment: There's nothing on that link, it expired.